# How to keep unrounded number in result from arithmetic operations in a SELECT statement?

Tags: sql

I have use a query statement to get a number from arithmetic operations in a select statement. But the number in the result just automatic rounded that cause a false value in return. So how do I keep the result number to be unrounded in this statement?

```
select ((100 - 10) / 100) * 100000.00 as number;
```

The result number should be 90000 but actually it return a zero (0). So could you help me with this?

Comment: Which database? Your Q will behave differently on different databases? CAST is your friend

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use decimal in the inner hundred also

```
select ((100 - 10) / 100.0) * 100000.00 as number;
```

Comment: So how do I remove 00000000 in the end of result number? The result number from your statement is 90000.00000000

Comment: SELECT cast((100 - 10) / 100.0 * 100000.00 AS NUMERIC(36,2)) as number;

Comment: Amazing! Thank so much. Sorry but I don't have enough reputation to mark this as the correct answer. But thank you.

Comment: @Trind07 You can mark it correct with the green mark, you cant upvote yet.